# How to convert a tuple in robot framework into list

Tags: robotframework

After executing a mysql query, got the results in the form of tuple in robot framework.

In order to do further operations, I would need to convert that tuple into list.

Ex:

```
@{id}=    Query    select column1 from table_name where column2 = '${var1}' and column = '${var2}'
```

Here the @{id} would be returned as a tuple.

EX :

```
( (1), (4) )
```

Now I need to convert the above tuple into  list as below :

```
[ 1, 4 ]
```

Comment: are you sure that `@{id}` is a tuple? When I run python code that returns a tuple, `@{id}` is a list.

Comment: @BryanOakley the DB API specs specify a sequence of sequences, so the type may vary between implementing APIs. MySQLdb returns tuples as in the question.

Comment: So, what you're really asking is to convert a list (or tuple) of tuples into a single list? What you showed doesn't look like a valid tuple of tuples -- `(1)` is not a python tuple (it seems to be missing a comma). Are you certain your data looks like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only had a tuple, you could use Convert To List or Create List. But here you have a tuple of tuples. I think the most clean way to extract the values from a column and create a list is as follows:

```
${column 1}    Evaluate    [x[0] for x in $id]
```

If your query had a second column, you could extract it similarly:

```
${column 2}    Evaluate    [x[1] for x in $id]
```

Comment: I was able to convert tuple into list. : 

${var}= Evaluate [x[-1] for x in $id]

TO extract last element in the above list :

Log ${var[-1]}