# RF: Convert List of Tuple to List of List

Tags: python, robotframework

I have fetched data from DB and got this tuple. And I am using below code to convert tuple into list.but output is coming index wise. like

```
${Rows}   [('3/6/2018', '16', '8', '50.00', '3024', '1349', '44.61'), ('3/5/2018', '16', '9', '56.25', '3024', '2114', '69.91'), ('3/4/2018', '16', '9', '56.25', '3024', '2224', '73.54')]

${RowWise}   create list
: FOR   ${j}   IN RANGE  0  7
\   ${row}=    Evaluate    [x[${j}] for x in ${Rows}]
\   append To list   ${RowWise}   ${row}

Log List  ${RowWise}
```

Above code returns this

```
[('3/6/2018','3/6/2018','3/6/2018','3/6/2018','3/6/2018','3/6/2018'), ('16','16','16','16','16',)....]
```

I want something like this

```
[['3/6/2018', '16', '8', '50.00', '3024', '1349', '44.61'], ['3/5/2018', '16', '9', '56.25', '3024', '2114', '69.91'], ['3/4/2018', '16', '9', '56.25', '3024', '2224', '73.54']]
```

Could you please help me here?

Note: using python iam able to get solution. but trying to implement in robot Framework.

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511116/how-to-convert-a-tuple-in-robot-framework-into-list#35512488).

Comment: thx for your time. Took the same reference and constructed this code.  That is useful if one want data Column wise. But i want ROW wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good case where list comprehension can be used.

We can convert tuples to lists as

```
x = list((1,2))
```

For your example

```
x = [('3/6/2018', '16', '8', '50.00', '3024', '1349', '44.61'), ('3/5/2018', '16', '9', '56.25', '3024', '2114', '69.91'), ('3/4/2018', '16', '9', '56.25', '3024', '2224', '73.54')]
x = [list(i) for i in x]
print(x)
```

> [['3/6/2018', '16', '8', '50.00', '3024', '1349', '44.61'], 
>   ['3/5/2018', '16', '9', '56.25', '3024', '2114', '69.91'], 
>   ['3/4/2018', '16', '9', '56.25', '3024', '2224', '73.54']]

---

Using the answer provided [How to convert a tuple in robot framework into list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511116/how-to-convert-a-tuple-in-robot-framework-into-list#35512488)

We can change this to

```
${Row 1}    Evaluate    [list(x) for x in $id]
```

Comment: Thanks JahKnows. This is what i need. it works pretty well